# How to convert string to value type on model binding in ASP.NET Core mvc

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller

This is my model

```cs
public class MyModel
{
   public string Title { get; set; }

   public string Code { get; set; }

   public string Description { get; set; }

   public Guid InstructorId { get; set; }
}
```

And this is how I plan to use it with model binder.

```cs
 public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
 {
     if (bindingContext == null)
     {
         throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
     }

     var model = new CreateCourseRequestModel();

     var properties = typeof(CreateCourseRequestModel).GetProperties();

     foreach (var property in properties)
     {
         var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(property.Name); // prop value
          property.SetValue(model, value.FirstValue);
     }

     bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model);

     return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

If all properties are of type `string`, then there is no problem.

If any property is not in string type then there should be a problem.

**Question**

How do I parse `string` to the desired property type in model binder?

Thank you

Comment: Do you want to bind the model in a controller action automatically?

Comment: What is the definition of `CreateCourseRequestModel` ? Where did you put the custom model binder?

Answer (score -1):

I have a question. Why do you use a Custom Model Binder?

The default can handle your current example model without any problems.

```
[HttpPost]
public Task<IActionResult> Post(MyModel model) { .. }
```

in the Controller should work.

Or perhabs I missunderstood your question.